# package need to return execution plan and statistic of the query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Suppose i  execute my script in sql plus as shown below

```
sql>set autotrace traceonly;
sql>select * from employees;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=2 Card=14 Bytes=1 K)
   1    0    TABLE ACCESS FULL T416493.EMPLOYEE (Cost=2 Card=14 Bytes=1 K)

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
      6  user calls
      0  physical read total multi block requests
      0  physical read total bytes
      0  cell physical IO interconnect bytes
      0  commit cleanout failures: block lost
      0  IMU commits
      0  IMU Flushes
      0  IMU contention
      0  IMU bind flushes
      0  IMU mbu flush
     14  rows processed
```

i am creating a package ,where i pass the query and it will provide me the execution plan with this statistic .How can i implement this is package ?

Comment: Take a look at the DBMS_XPLAN package [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_xplan.htm), also the table SYS.PLAN_TABLE$ and the PUBLIC.PLAN_TABLE view.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: PUBLIC.PLAN_TABLE is a synonym, not a view.  Doh!

Comment: @tbone: i m blank right now:) ,no idea how to get this

Comment: in your procedure, run an explain plan for the query, and use dbms_xplan to display results (plan and stats).  See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan.php for more on using dbms_xplan.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic wrapper for DMBS_XPLAN.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_plan(p_sql IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'explain plan for '||p_sql;

  FOR r_plan IN (SELECT * 
                 FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY))
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r_plan.plan_table_output);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

BEGIN
  print_plan('select 1 from dual');
END;
/
```

Comment: i am interested in statistic ,what i have shown in my question nyways thanks